# What are the arched things above a wheel called?

Tags: part-identification, terminology

I have a bunch of second hand bricks and some are "wheel wells" for the lack of better words.

I would like to find out how I use them for example at bricklink, but then I need to find the name for such a thing first

[image]

Comment: I call these mudguards or wheel arches

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is a [Vehicle, Mudguard 2 x 4 with Arch Studded](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3788) (and a darn hard part to figure out at that).

Comment: Very nice - The crop was from a vehicle I found on the net - strangely enough I have many more that do not show up as mudguards - some of them are part of a "chassis" as well... I guess I will need to photograph them all :)

Comment: I've spent about half an hour yesterday looking for this on Bricklink and failed miserably. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

i'm calling those things "fenders" (don't know the "official" name, too).

**EDIT:**
if found [wheel arch 2x4](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) in the LEGO-shop. this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but looks like a "newer version" - so maybe we should call those pieces "wheel arches" in the future.